Why does making an assignment inside an if statement evaluate differently from making the assignment beforehand
I am assigning a variable to the first element of a list.
If I make the assignment inside an if statement, I get a different value than if I assign it outside the statement.
Like this:
$ perl -E 'my @y = (0, 1) ;  my $x; if (($x) = @y) {say qq[yes ], $x} else {say q[no ], $x}'
yes 0

vs
$ perl -E 'my @y = (0, 1) ; my ($x) = @y; if ($x) {say qq[yes ], $x} else {say q[no ], $x}'
no 0

Why are the results different?
Is there a way to make the assignment inside the if statement and check its value?

You are evaluating a list assignment (( ... ) = ...) in scalar context in the first case. This returns the number of scalars to which its RHS evaluates. You are evaluating a scalar ($x) in scalar context in the other. This returns the scalar itself.

The if-condition imposes a scalar context on your statement. The results are different because in the first one-liner you do:
if (2)      # return value = @y (size)

And in the second case you do:
if (0)      # return value = $x (value)

The return value of the statement ($x) = @y is not the value of $x, it becomes the size of @y. Like in the list counting idiom:
my $n = () = (list here);

Except in your case the first scalar assignment is implicit:
if-context = ($x) = @y

You finish with an additional question: Is there a way to make the assignment inside the if statement?
Yes, you can use the array value directly and not use list assignment.
if ( $x = $y[0] )     # the return value of the statement is 0

You can also use a subscript
if ( $x = (@y)[0] )   # the return value of the statement is 0

You can shift a value off the array, though this changes the array of course.
if ( $x = shift @y )

